# How to read the property values setup for ActiveJDBC?

Tags: java, activejdbc, javalite

I am using the activejdbc.properties file to specify the location of my database.properties values.

**activejdbc.properties**

```
env.connections.file=/opt/apps/conf/database.properties
```

**database.properties**  (Located on the server)

```
development.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
development.username=myusername
development.password=mypassword
development.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dburl:1521/testdb.world
```

What I am trying to do now is use Connection Pooling.   I've examined your example how to do this, however I'm not fully understanding how to pull my database property values to help create the connection pool.

Here's your example:

```
public void shouldUseConnectionFromPool() throws PropertyVetoException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(driver());
        DataSource dataSourceUnpooled = DataSources.unpooledDataSource(url(), user(), password());
        DataSource dataSourcePooled = DataSources.pooledDataSource(dataSourceUnpooled); //init the connection pool
        Base.open(dataSourcePooled); //get connection from pool
        Person.deleteAll(); //clean DB before test
        Person.createIt("name", "Matt", "last_name", "Diamont", "dob", "1962-01-01");
        a(Person.findAll().size()).shouldBeEqual(1);

        Person.deleteAll();//clean DB after test
        Base.close();// really connection goes back to pool
        DataSources.destroy(dataSourcePooled);//shut down the pool
    }
```

And here's mine.  I'm using JavaSpark and trying to define my pool in the main() so when the server is spun up.

```
public static void main(String[] clargs) {

        try {
            DataSource dataSourceUnpooled = DataSources.unpooledDataSource("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//dburl:1521/testdb.world", "myusername", "mypassword");
            dataSourcePooled = DataSources.pooledDataSource(dataSourceUnpooled); //init the connection pool
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        before("/*", (req, res) -> {

            if (!Base.hasConnection()) {
                System.out.println("Database Connection OPEN.");
                Base.open(dataSourcePooled); //get connection from pool  ;
            }
         }

         after("/*", (req, res) -> {    
            Base.close(); // really connection goes back to pool
        });

        get("/exit", (req,res)->{
            if (Base.hasConnection()) {
                Base.close(); // really connection goes back to pool
            }
            DataSources.destroy(dataSourcePooled); //shut down the pool

            System.exit(0);
            return "Application shutdown";
        });
}
```

So now I'm trying to remove my hardcoded property values and used what is setup in my files.    I see you using url(), etc but not sure if that's a private method you created for your tests.   So my question is, is there an easy way to use URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD etc from what's pulled in by ActiveJDBC or do I need to just read the file on the server and manually pull it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

-> Delete file `activejdbc.properties`.

-> Since Spark is running Jetty, use the Jetty to configure a JDBC pool: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource

-> Create a property file `/opt/apps/conf/database.properties` with this content:

`development.jndi=java:comp/env/jdbc/acme`

-> Rewrite your program:

```
public static void main(String[] clargs) {
    before("/*", (req, res) -> {
       Base.open(); //will pickup 'development' connection from property file 
    });
    after("/*", (req, res) -> {
        Base.close(); // really connection goes back to pool
    });
    get("/exit", (req, res) -> {
        System.exit(0);
        return "Application shutdown";
    });
}
```

I guess you need to add more methods to get any work done.

Start your program:

```
java com.company.project.Main -cp myprogram.jar -Denv.connections.file=/opt/apps/conf/database.properties
```

See more:
http://javalite.io/database_connection_management#location-of-property-file